# How to disable Firefox 43's search/preview/magnifying glass feature?

Tags: firefox, feature-regression

Like most new Firefox features, the only thing I want to do with them is turn them off.  Firefox 42 or 43 implemented this new search/preview/magnifying glass thing, and trying to search The Internets for a way to turn it off has not been fruitful thus far.

[This link talks about Chrome as far as I can tell](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/dkJ2qUDD3Yc), and it's from 2010.  The feature I'm referring to is very new.[image: Here is an example of what I'm referring to]

Is there a way to turn this off?  Usually there's a setting in about:config that disable the new features that they roll out.

Answer (score 0):

Classic Theme Restorer

Extension that helps getting rid of the various "improvements" mozilla is introducing.

Comment: At least provide a link...